# Dotfuscator - ${configuration} ${platform} is empty in VS Class Library project

Tags: dotfuscator

I've class VS Class Library project (.Net Core 2.2) and Dotfuscator not recognising the `${configuration}` and `${platform}` variables in configuration file.

```
<inputassembly refid="a8cc280e-26a3-476e-8e29-5a0cfc0000b1">
    <file dir="${configdir}\bin\${configuration}\netcoreapp2.2" name="Common.dll" />
</inputassembly>
```

`${configuration}` is empty but `$(configdir)` works as expected.

Similary

```
<mapoutput overwrite="true">
   <file dir="${configdir}\Reports\${configuration}\${platform}" name="Renaming.xml" />
</mapoutput>
```

returns

```
...\Reports\\\Renaming.xml
```

Dotfuscator version: 4.4

Config file generated by Dotfuscator

No `<propertylist>`

Comment: I'm on the Dotfuscator team. Could you edit your question to clarify the following? (1) What version / edition of Dotfuscator are you using? (2) Was this config file generated by Dotfuscator or was it manually created using the Dotfuscator Config Editor? (3) Does the config file have a `<propertylist>` tag, and if so, what are the contents? (4) Is the behavior the same if you try to build using the config file and if you open the file in the Dotfuscator Config Editor?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. Something seems to be off about the `<inputassembly>` tag - that shouldn't be using the `${configuration}` property, because it (and `${platform}`) are only defined when building the project from Visual Studio / MSBuild. Since you're using Dotfuscator Professional, you can [contact support](https://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support) to better diagnose the problem.